# How do I answer this homework question about a class declaration in Java?

Tags: java

`ClassA` extends `Object`. Given the legal instantiations of:

```
InterfaceB myGuy = new ClassA();
```

and

```
ClassA myGuy = new ClassA();
```

What would the first line of the class declaration for `ClassA` likely be?

FYI, my last attempted answer was - "public class classA implements interfaceB {...}"

Yes, this is a homework question from a java noob. I would appreciate a good point in the right direction. Adolescent negative commentary can be kept to yourself...thank you.

Comment: I'll give you a clue...it has the word `implements` in it

Comment: Given that this is a homework question because thats how it's phrased. Might I suggest you come up with several answers and ask us which we think is the best and why. The best way to learn is to attempt the answer first and learn from your mistakes. Not expect others to do the work for you.

Comment: This is like a person (aspiring to be a mechanic, no doubt) going to a Mechanics-r-us website and asking how they use a hammer. If you go through the basic tutorials and understand it, this will become obvious.

Comment: Guys...

I know we all want to help people, that's why we post answers. But when dealing with questions that either are or appear to be homework questions, can I encourage everyone to:

1. First encourage the poster to attempt to find an answer themselves so they go through the learning process.

2. Only if they are still confused or not sure, discuss their answers or post a correct answer.

If we keep giving the answers to questions like this without the OP making any attempt at it themselves, they they won't learn anything and will keep bugging us for the free lunches.

Comment: Why in god's green earth does everyone assume the user didn't try - for the past 3 weeks - to answer this question, and after being exhausted in attempting to understand what is being asked...posted it here for some sort of help?

Comment: Another - more pressing - question is the following....Are other users allowed to retitle someone else's question? Yes, this is in fact a homework question. However, this is not the title I gave this question when posting it online. FYI, my last attempted answer was - "public class classA implements interfaceB {...}"

Comment: @thefonso Yes, other users are allowed to retitle and even change the body of the question.  Also, don't worry too much about the complainers -- basic questions are fine.  If it's a school question, make sure to say so in the question or tag it as homework *and be sure to include what you've already tried* so that people know you're making an effort.  If people know it's homework, they may try to guide you towards an answer rather than giving it to you outright.

Comment: @Jonathon Thanks for your response, I'll make sure to do that. As it turns out my original answer was correct. But I really appreciated Erik robertson's clue. It validated my thinking process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that this line is legal:

```
InterfaceB myGuy = new ClassA();
```

In order for that assignment to be legal, `ClassA` has to extend or implement `InterfaceB`.  You know that `ClassA` extends `Object`, so it can't extend `InterfaceB`.  So `InterfaceB` must be an interface instead of a class.

The first line of the interface declaration for `InterfaceB` is:

```
public interface InterfaceB {
```

So what would the first line of the class declaration for `ClassA` be?

Comment: public class classA implements InterfaceB {...} [note: this is what i put as an answer for the homework]

Answer (score 1):

The clue is obviously the name in the first of the two legal instantiations: `InterfaceB`.

When you declare a variable, you can instantiate (with the `new` keyword) any *type* of object that is derived from (by subclassing) or implements (from an interface) the declared type.

So `InterfaceB` is either an interface implemented by `ClassA` or a superclass of `ClassA`.

Comment: Just because it is called `InterfaceB` doesn't make it an interface.  Also, `InterfaceB` cannot be a superclass of `ClassA` since the first thing the OP said was that `ClassA` extends `Object`.

Comment: @Erick Robertson: I didn't intend to mean that because it's named `InterfaceB` that it must be an interface -- only that the question was trying to nudge the answerer towards a particular solution.  You can have more than one superclass -- `ClassA` can extend a class called `InterfaceB`, and `Object` is a superclass of both.  Nothing in the question prohibits `InterfaceB` from being a superclass of `ClassA`.  It *suggests* that it's an interface, but doesn't explicitly require this outcome.

Comment: Actually, it says `ClassA` extends `Object`.  The word "extend" has a very specific meaning in Java.  It means that `ClassA` is an immediate subclass of `Object`.  This means that `InterfaceB` could not be a superclass of `ClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is

```
InterfaceB interfaceB{};
```

and `ClassA` implemented it;

```
ClassA imeplements interfaceB {}
```

so you can init. InterfaceB like

```
InterfaceB interfaceB = new ClassA ();
```

you know the second one